# php - upload csv file not being stored to $_FILES

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have this basic upload code:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" >
<input type="file" name="file" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo '<h3>Post test: </h3>';
    var_dump($_POST);
    $csv = array();

    if(isset($_FILES["file"])) {
        //if there was an error uploading the file
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else {
            //Print file details
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "No file selected <br />";
    }
}
```

I keep getting "No file selected" which is the else fallback of `isset($_FILES['file']`.

Would there be something in my php.ini file that I would need to set to allow me to upload files to a temp location?  Is there something I need to do, other than submitting the form to set the file to `$_FILES`?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in the form tag:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: *sigh* it's always the enctype.

Comment: Perfect.  Much appreciated.